# filter/ search for google markers

Tags: php, mysql, json

i using map.html where is google map api with markers who gets markers on zoom (self.jqXHR = $.post( `"script.php", JSON.stringify(data),  this.onDataFetched);`), and i have script.php where is query from mysql who is getting me markers

everything works great but i would like to implement html form in map.html, who can change sql query script.php page

can someone help me to get solution? what i should write in form statment?
 at now i have something like this `<form  method="post" action="script.php"  id="searchform">` , but then it goes to script.php - what i can do?

im using code described there : http://blog.loleksy.pl/2014/02/02/google-maps-handling-huge-amount-of-markers/

i have added to HTML file form like this in `<body>` tags:

```
 <form  method="post" action="script.php"  id="searchform">
  city <input  type="text" name="city"><br>
  <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="filter"></form>
```

i just sad - my code is like in example:

```
<?php

/* config */
$config = array(
    'user' => 'someuser',
    'password' => 'somepassword',
    'dbName' => 'somedb',
    'host' => 'localhost'
);

/* connection */
$pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host='.$config['host'].';dbname='.$config['dbName'],$config['user'], $config['password']);
$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
/* request */
$data = @file_get_contents('php://input');
if(!$data){
    exit;
}
$data = json_decode($data, true);

/* logic */
function getResults($db, $data, $maxResults = 500){
    /* filter data */
    if(!isset($data['southWest']['lat']) || !isset($data['northEast']['lat']) ||
                !isset($data['southWest']['lng']) || !isset($data['northEast']['lng'])){
            return array ('needZoom' => false, 'markers' => array());
    }
    $a = (float)$data['southWest']['lat'];
    $b = (float)$data['southWest']['lng'];
    $c = (float)$data['northEast']['lat'];
    $d = (float)$data['northEast']['lng'];

    $condition1 = $a < $c ? "lat BETWEEN $a AND $c":"lat BETWEEN $c AND $a";
    $condition2 = $b < $d ? "lng BETWEEN $b AND $d":"lng BETWEEN $d AND $b";
    /* get count */
    $countQuery = "
        SELECT COUNT(id) as count 
        FROM ex1_cities 
        WHERE 
        ( $condition1 ) AND ( $condition2 )
    ";

    $countStmt = $db->query($countQuery);
    $countResult = $countStmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $count = (int)$countResult['count'];
    /* need zoom */
    if($count>$maxResults){ 
        return array('needZoom' => true);   
    }
    /* get markers */
    $resultQuery = "
        SELECT id, name, country_code, lat, lng 
        FROM ex1_cities 
        WHERE 
        ( $condition1 ) AND ( $condition2 )
    ";
    $resultStmt = $db->query($resultQuery);
    $result = $resultStmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return array(
    'needZoom' => false,
    'markers' => $result
    );

}

$output = getResults($pdo, $data);

/* response */
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($output);
```

with html form i want modified this part  - according to form data

```
$resultQuery = "
            SELECT id, name, country_code, lat, lng 
            FROM ex1_cities 
            WHERE 
            ( $condition1 ) AND ( $condition2 )
        ";
```

THANKS!

Comment: what are trying to do? get variable then post with ajax to show google maps? not clear to me..

Comment: i add source of code im using

Comment: i dont see any form yo post, show me the `<form  method="post" action="script.php"  id="searchform">`

Comment: i added form like example

Comment: just read your link decribed given, the sample use ajax to grab json as refer to this line `self.jqXHR = $.post( "get_markers.php", JSON.stringify(data),  this.onDataFetched);` then set `lat, lng, name` so are your **script.php** do the same thing or something else?

Comment: what i need to write in form? can it be done by method POST? and action to "script.php" to change SQL query?

Comment: its possible to post your variable to its own file and then re-initilize the map again with your new `lat, lng, name` array, please describe what is is your `script.php` for and show the code

Comment: i just sad - my code is like in example:

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is your expect..?
this code below its just post your `input city` then adapt to your query
what is your expecting?

> lot marker on google maps that have query like city?
>   please describe your output desire!

```html
$city = $_POST['city']
$resultQuery = "
            SELECT id, name, country_code, lat, lng 
            FROM ex1_cities 
            WHERE 
            city = '$city'
        ";
```

Comment: something like this but  this doesnt work - html page redirects to .php page after submit search form
i want page reloads after submit  -  according to new query give google markers

Comment: you can use ajax so it will post to your php without redirecting, then call function to initialize your map, or maybe change `action="script. php"` to empty `action=""` if you using 1 php files

Comment: you giving me answers without any background information :)
how i can use ampty action, if i sad - i have .html and .php files. can you give me example when i can merge this files (source code of both files are in link) in one file? thanks

Comment: @smartkaspars see next answer please

Comment: my sample is have 'header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($output);'  if im putting all together im getting parse error

Comment: @smartkaspars based on example you are using, **.html** files use **json** data that proccess and filter with query in **.php** files  then set markers in **.html** files with ajax with `this.onBoundsChanged = function()` this funcition, so tell me what is your logic you want to do? the code sample i write here is for not `html page redirects to .php page after submit` as your comment

Answer (score 0):

This is simple one page as i mention on comment
please adapt this code to your code
on this example if you type **bandung** it wil direct your map to Bandung
otherwise **Jakarta** and empty default to **Bandung**

```html
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
    $city = $_POST['searchcity'];
    if (!empty($city)) {
        //** This is your query should print if input is not empty **//
        if ($city != "bandung") {
            $printcity = "'Jakarta'";
            $latlon = '-6.203, 106.8451';
        }
    }
    else {
        //** This is your query should print if input is empty **//
        $printcity = "'Bandung'";
        $latlon = '-6.9034494, 107.6431576';
    }
}
else {
    //** This is your query should print if not submit **//
    $printcity = "'Bandung'";
    $latlon = '-6.9034494, 107.6431576';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple markers</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      .search {
      position: fixed;
      border-radius: 2px;
      float: left;
      height: 30px;
      line-height: 30px;
      margin: 20px 0px 0px 80px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      width: 500px;
      z-index: 50;
    }
    #searchsite {
      padding: 0px 11px 0px 13px;
      font-size: 15px;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      border-radius: 2px 0px 0px 2px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      height: 32px;
      outline: medium none;
      box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latlon ?>);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: <?php echo $printcity ?>
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="search">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" id="searchcity" name="searchcity" size="45px" placeholder="site name(lowercse)">
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

save it as **whatever**.php you want
let me know the result.
and this line is what I've mention eave **action** empty

```html
<form action="" method="post">
```

Comment: my sample is have 'header('Content-Type: application/json'); echo json_encode($output);' if im putting all together im getting parse error